# Spring data jpa @ManyToOne orphanRemoval=true doesn't delete

Tags: java, mysql, orm, spring-data-jpa

Situation: Got Books and categories. Each category can have n books. Want to create new, update or delete books from category. If category is empty delete it from db. Currently insert, update, and delete books.

**Problem:  orphanRemoval=true doesn't delete category if it is empty.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@Getter
@Setter
public class BookEntity implements DBEntity, Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String bookname;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CategoryEntity categoryEntity;

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@Getter
@Setter

public class CategoryEntity implements DBEntity, Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "categoryEntity", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BookEntity> bookEntitySet = new HashSet<BookEntity>(0);

}

@Transactional
public interface CategoryDAO extends CrudRepository<CategoryEntity, Integer> {
}

@Transactional
public interface BookDAO extends CrudRepository<BookEntity, Integer> {
}
```

Thanks for any help

p.s.
Tried:  
*didnt help:* 
[Spring + JPA @OneToMany with orphanRemoval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374520/spring-jpa-onetomany-with-orphanremoval) 
*looks stupid - deleting book from category (in case 2-n foreign key wont work):* 
https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/ 
 *Nothing mentioned:* 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/